# Apache Solr only returning results if wildcard character (*) is present (with Magento)

Tags: magento, solr

I have Solr set up with Magento Enterprise Edition 1.9 and for the most part it works well. However, there are certain terms (e.g. "banana") which return no results even though product names in my catalog contain the word "banana".

However, as soon as I search for "banana*", with a wildcard, it returns results as expected.

I have used Magento's default schema for Solr so I don't have experience in tweaking Solr's schema file, so any advice would be appreciated.

**Edit:** here is a link to both my schema and config files:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d7a7106eb4e594d5adc

**Edit 2:** exploring my index using [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) I noticed that when I changed my default field from "fulltext" to "fulltext1_en" or "name_en", my normal query "banana" worked as expected. When I made this change in my schema, the search is working as expected. This leads me to more questions, however: I'm not sure how "fulltext" relates to "fulltext1_en". Why does "fulltext" not work but "fulltext1_en" does? Doesn't "fulltext" exist since it's in the Magento schema? And how was I getting *any* search results at all if the "fulltext" field simply didn't exist in my schema?

Comment: please post this default schema and config, solr query will be helpful as well

Comment: I have done so now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your schema, standard keyword searches in solr only return results for that exact word not partially. Like you said, adding a wildcard will work much like a regex expression but some results will just be rubbish.

One workaround is to add a spellcheck component:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
    <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
    <str name="field">textsuggest</str>
    <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Add in your request handler the component

```
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">3</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>

    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
```

Or you can create new fields similar to an autocomplete like:

```
<!-- autocomplete_edge : Will match from the left of the field, e.g. if the document field
         is "A brown fox" and the query is "A bro", it will match, but not "brown"
    -->
    <fieldType name="autocomplete_edge" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,;:-_])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,;:-_])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(.{30})(.*)?" replacement="$1" replace="all"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

<field name="textnge" type="autocomplete_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

Comment: I have edited to add my schema. When you say it only matches the "exact word"... the search term is not a partial word, it's an exact. A product can be called "Ancient Banana Hammock", and when I search for "Banana", it's not working. I might expect issues if I searched "nana" but "Banana" should work?

Comment: [Query parser syntax wildcards](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) of solr gets you more results, much like a regex. If you look for "Banana" in "Ancient Banana Hammock" the default solr search won't return anything but If you search for "Banana*" then you're telling solr to look for one or more occurrence of "Banana" (solr is case sensitive by default I believe). The "/spell" requestHandler in your schema does not seem to be correct, but you can try "/terms" handler, so that qt=/terms (.../solr/collection/terms?q=Banana...) and see what it returns.